# Find elements in N-nested list and remove by specific property

Tags: java, list, object, nested, removeall

I'm trying to find and remove from a main object a certain number of sub//sub/sub//..(unknown nested level) elements. My situation is like this:

Root object:

```java
public class Root {
    public int id;
    public int type;
    public String name;
    public List<Son> sons;
    ....
}
```

The main object (Root) has a list of Son that can have N nested lists of Son objects.
Son object shares the same 3 variables names like root, plus other properties.
Since I'm not able to know how deep nesting would be, I'm trying to find a way to find inside this nested Son objects, the multiple elements I want to remove that matches a specified property (int type==1).

I've tried with stream, but maybe I'm not capable enough to fit the right commands upon the code.
Something like this:

```
List<Son> firstNode = root.getSons();

firstNode.stream()
        .forEach(c -> {
            if(c.geType()==1){
                firstNode.remove(c);
                logger.info("###############################>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+c.getName());
            }
});
```

However, this doesn't work.

I've tried with a while too, counting the deepest node of the object, but nodes may vary from subnode to subnode.

Any suggestions?

Trying to make you understand more the situation, I've made a diagram about how the object may be and where the type==1 are:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGc2g.png

Comment: One of the key principles while using Streams is, don't modify the "source".  Seems you are ignoring it. NOTE: This may not be the root cause for your issue.

Comment: For your given code, what is the out when there is Son A with type 1 and contains Son B, C where B with type 1 and C with type 2? You remove all of them or keep C?

Comment: Just to clarify, based on your description, if any `son.type` is one that should be removed, then there is no need to check the list since it will be removed with its containing son.  So if the root has that type, you will be left with no elements of Son whatsover.

Comment: I just need to remove an element that can be in any position deep in the nest of Son(s) that meets the matched property. It seems that stream is not the right thing to do.

Comment: @DanielMax  So using your diagram, if you remove a Son which has type==3 you will only have two son's left.  It makes no sense to check the decendents of a "Type 3" son if that son is to be removed.

Comment: @WJS in fact i've specified type==1 that is the objective to reach. Those are the elements to remove

Comment: @DanielMax  I have asked a simple question and  you still refuse to answer it.  What if you specified type == 3?  What would you expect the result to be?

Comment: @WJS i didn't understand that yours was a question, anyway i won't do nothing if the type is 3. The goal is to remove only the type 1.

Comment: Well, I provided you a solution that worked on a test data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try this. I had to make some assumptions.  It will remove all of a given type except the root.  Also, you should make the root an instance of Son for this to work.  You don't really need a separate root class.

Simply call this with the root instance of Son and the type to be removed.

```
public static void remove(Son son, int type) {  
    if (son == null) {
          return;
    }
    Iterator<Son> iter = son.sons.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        Son s = iter.next();
        if (s.type == type) {
            iter.remove();
        } else {
           if (s.sons != null) {
              remove(s, type);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. i just needed to put a return before the Iterator if the son.sons is null to evade the NullPointerException. Very thanks so Iteration was the solution. Thanks again for your effort and time on helping me

Comment: Yeah, I didn't completely check for null lists, etc.  Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

*Because that the number is not known* , you need to use a **recursive method** to visit all the Tree.

Recursion is the technique of making a function call itself. This technique provides a way to break complicated problems down into simple problems which are easier to solve.

you need to fix a return condition first : for example
if ( listOfSon.isEmpty()) return;

And then you need to do your business logic.
After that the method need to call itself for all the Sons like that you garantee that your method will visit all existent node.

**you can search for : recursion in java , Traversing through all nodes of a Tree in java** . that will really give you a great idea about what you need

**You may change the class Node to extends from the class Root** to avoid writing another conditions

```
  static void removeNode(Root r) {
    if (r.sons!=null && !r.sons.isEmpty()) {

        for (Son s : r.sons) {
            if (s.type == 1) {
                removeNode(s);
            }
        }
        for (Son s : r.sons) {
            if (s.type == 1) {
                r.sons.remove(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Be carefull with deleting element from an ArrayList when iterating the ArrayList because it can cause a ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: Thanks, i've just tryed your example and it seems it gets "stuck" on the first tree, so i've put a !=1 condition on the first for statement and it seems it goes deeper. But, as you predicted, when in the second for removes the node, it causes an Exception. I was thinking on trying a "cloning" of the object but without the elements that have type == 1. I'll keep testing

Comment: you are welcome ,I didnt give you the exact solution for the problem , just i tried to give you an example that can help you , you need to read about recursion inspire from the example and you will find the solution. if you need the exact solution for your code you need give the complete code of the problem .

Comment: Simply replacing the second for loop with `r.sons.removeIf(s -> s.type == 1);` trivially fixes the ConcurrentModificationException issue.

Comment: using CopyOnWriteArrayList is a suitable solution too, or just bofore the first for , declare a new ArrayList of Root where you can save the references of Sons to Remove , and replace the second for loop with one who delete all the element in the new ArrayList from the initial ArrayList of Nodes. ............||..........                        
          ArrayList<Root> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();
   for (Son s : r.sons) {
    if (s.type == 1) {
     toRemove.add(s);
     removeNode(s);
    }
   }
   for (Root toRem :toRemove) {
     r.sons.remove(toRem);
   }

Comment: Thank you. Your tips toghether with the Solution of @WJS worked at the end. Thanks for your effort and timing.